# SSIS script task is only working with debugging mode

Tags: c#, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, sendgrid

I am using VS 2017 and SQL server 2016 to do the job. I create a script task that tries to send email by using SendGrid. If I put a break point inside the script task, I won't have problem to execute my SSIS package and then get the email. However, if I simply execute the package, the entire package still can be executed successfully but I cannot get the email, which I suspect that script task does not get executed. The following is the code of my script task

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string User_Email = Dts.Variables["User::UserEmail"].Value.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::OutputPath"].Value.ToString()))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            File.Copy(Dts.Variables["User::OutputPath"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["User::DestinationPath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::co_num"].Value.ToString() + ".pdf", true);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

            SendGridMailHelper.SendOrderVerification(User_Email, "user name");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The file is not found in the specified location");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("SendGrid"))
        {
            string path = @"F:\DLL\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "SendGrid.dll"));
        }
        if (args.Name.Contains("System.Net.Http"))
        {
            string path = @"F:\DLL\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "System.Net.Http.dll"));
        }
        if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
        {
            string path = @"F:\DLL\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

To be safe, I checked the windows log and it showed the run time error when I run  the package without adding check points. However, I cannot figure it out what it means. Any thoughts will be very helpful. Thank you.

> Application: DtsDebugHost.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.MissingMethodException
>      at ST_b240be27e55248ea869be51aa06a2018.SendGridMailHelper+<_SendEmail>d__7.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[ST_b240be27e55248ea869be51aa06a2018.SendGridMailHelper+<_SendEmail>d__7, ST_b240be27e55248ea869be51aa06a2018, Version=1.0.6877.42064, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](<_SendEmail>d__7 ByRef)
>      at ST_b240be27e55248ea869be51aa06a2018.SendGridMailHelper._SendEmail(System.Collections.Generic.List`1, System.Object, System.String)
>      at ST_b240be27e55248ea869be51aa06a2018.SendGridMailHelper+d__9.MoveNext()
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Comment: you are executing package in two different ways, right? With Debug point & Without Debug point. so when your issue occurs? please edit your question for better understanding

Comment: @im_one I just edited it and please take a look.